# rosdoc generation for wiki

Tags: ros, rosdoc, rosdoc-lite

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I use the following command to generate a package's documentation:

```
rosdoc_lite [name-of-pkg]
```

When inspecting the resulting offline documentation, I noticed that it's different from the one autogenerated for the ros wiki under the Code API tab:

[http://ros.org/doc/groovy/api/[name-of-pkg]/html/index.html](http://ros.org/doc/groovy/api/%5Bname-of-pkg%5D/html/index.html)

In particular, the online version has all the auxiliary `srv::` and `cfg::` namespaces (and possibly others) hidden.

Two questions:

- Is there a way to generate documentation offline which is the same as the online one?
- If not, what exactly are the differences between the two?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/54243/rosdoc-generation-for-wiki/) by [Ivan Dryanovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/79/ivan-dryanovski/) on ROS Answers with karma: 4954 on 2013-02-04

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The documentation generated by rosdoc_lite should be the same as the documentation generated locally. I think the reason that you're getting the "srv" and "cfg" namespaces to show up is because you're running rosdoc_lite on a package that has been built. As such, there are a bunch of auto-generated header files that Doxygen is processing that aren't run by the automated doc system.

Do you have a specific package in mind that you're seeing this for? If I know what you're trying to replicate, I can double check that this is, indeed the case.

---

Originally posted by [eitan](https://answers.ros.org/users/107/eitan/) with karma: 2743 on 2013-02-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ivan Dryanovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/79/ivan-dryanovski/) on 2013-02-05**:
You're correct - running "make clean" before rosdoc_lite resolved the issue. Thanks!